# Incident triggered on Absence condition type when log-based metric is not absent

Tags: google-cloud-monitoring, google-alerts

I don't understand why an incident is being triggered looking at the following Policy details:

[image]

In the screenshot you can see that the incident is supposed to trigger after an absence time of 8 hours. The timeseries is representing the activity of the log-based metric of the last day. There is clearly no absence. Why is an incident being triggered? (you can see it in the incident section)

## edit

adding more screenshot

Policy details over a week

[image]

Incidents details

[image]

Comment: can you share some other screenshot of the issue you encountered? You might want also to contact [Google Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases#creating_cases)

Comment: @BryanL I've added more screenshot, especial one with incidents details.

Comment: tried to create my own metric absence trigger and only used default settings, I am also having the same alert and messages. I am reading this Google documentation on [alerting policies](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/concepts-indepth).

Comment: @BryanL thanks! Let me know if you find something!